# Powershell remove [ ] (brackets) and () parentheses from filenames

Tags: powershell, filenames, file-rename

I receive files from a source that places "[]" and "()" in the filenames.  I wrote a script that removes other characters (spaces and commas, etc...) and it does great on them, but it will not remove these characters and causes the rest of the script to fail if any of the files have these characters.

```
$directory = "D:\files"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $newName = $file.Name -replace " ", "."
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newName
}

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $newName = $file.Name -replace "\[", " "
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```

I even found a source online that said to lead it with a backslash but that does not work either.

I would prefer to create a script to remove them all and replace them with a period unless they are found at the beginning of the filename.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code as follows:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $directory |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '[][() ]', '.' -replace '^\.' }
```

- Your primary problem was the use of `-Path` instead of `-LiteralPath`: the former interprets a path as a [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expression, where `[` and `]` have special meaning, the latter does not.
- The above *implicitly* binds to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Rename-Item)'s `-LiteralPath` parameter, by directly providing file-information objects *via the pipeline*.
- Note the use of a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) (`{ ... }`) with the `-NewName` parameter, which allows you to determine the new name dynamically, for each pipeline input object, reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).
- The first [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) used with the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator replaces spaces, `(`, `)`, `[` and `]` characters with `.`, and the second one removes a `.` from the start of the resulting name, should there be one.

Note that there's a possibility that renames may fail, if they result in duplicate file names.

Comment: That worked amazingly well.  

There are some places now that it has 2 periods together.  can I add something to remove them and replace with a single one, or just remove one of the 2?

Lastly, I understand all but the `-replace '[][() ]'` portion.  I thought it was allowing you to add things to replace, but you have the brackets in there twice.

Comment: @KeithJones, adding another `-replace` operation, `-replace '\.+', '.'` would turn any run of two or more `.` into a single `.` Enclosing a set of characters in `[...]` makes the regex engine match any one of them. It just so happens that `[` and `]` are also part of that set in your case, which looks strange, but works as intended.